# Ubuntu 20.04 LTS sound option settings problem, doesn't detect headphone automatically I've to choose options manually

Tags: sound, 20.04, headphones

I've been using 20.04 LTS for a while in my Dell Vostro 5590. Previously I used 18.04. The sound settings were just fine. The problem with the 20.04 LTS is when I connect headphones, it doesn't detect them automatically. I have to choose settings manually in sound settings. It is frustrating when I have important zoom meetings. How do I fix this?

Thanks :)